MessageFilter.check_update() telegram
This is the code for the Telegram bot that I'm testing:
from typing import Final
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes
import sys
# function that implements the message handler
TOKEN: Final = 'BOT_TOKEN'
BOT_USERNAME: Final = '@flissi_bot'

# command
async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("Hi! I'm pizza_bot . I can help you with your shopping needs.")


async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("Hi! I'm pizza_bot. tape somthing so i can help you.")


async def custom_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("the a custon command.")

# reponses
def handel_responses(text: str) -> str:

    processed: str = text.lower()

    if 'hello' in processed:
        return 'hello'
    if 'how are you' in processed:
        return 'I am fine, thank you'
    if 'goodbye' in processed:
        return 'goodbye'
    if 'thank you' in processed:
        return 'you are welcome'

    return 'I do not understand you'


async def handel_message(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    message_type: str = update.message.chat.type
    text: str = update.message.text

    print(f'User ({update.message.chat_id})in {message_type}: "{text}"')

    if message_type == 'group':
        if BOT_USERNAME in text:
            new_text: str = text.replace(BOT_USERNAME, '').strip()
            response: str = handel_responses(new_text)
        else:
            return
    else:
        response: str = handel_responses(text)
    print('Bot', response)
    await update.message.reply_text(response)


async def error(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f'Update "{update}" caused error "{context.error}"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('starting bot...')
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    # commands
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('custom', custom_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help_command))

    # Messages
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Text, handel_message))

    # Errors
    app.add_error_handler(error)

    # Poll the bot
    print('polling bot...')
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)


I get the following error:
"Update(message=Message(channel_chat_created=False, chat=Chat(first_name='Flissi', id=6143267777, last_name='Hamed', type=<ChatType.PRIVATE>), date=datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 10, 2, 22, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), delete_chat_photo=False, from_user=User(first_name='Flissi', id=6143267777, is_bot=False, language_code='en', last_name='Hamed'), group_chat_created=False, message_id=28, supergroup_chat_created=False, text='hello'), update_id=589857240)" caused error "MessageFilter.check_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'"

can any one help?

what version of the telegram library are you using for your project?

Version: 21.1.1

@FlissiHamed do never share your telegram bot token with anyone as people can gain access to your bot with it (I edited the question no need to worry)

You left your Private Bot Token in your code. You should revoke it ASAP by talking to the @BotFather. People might abuse the token. It's still visible in the histoyr.

it's just for testing purpose

telegram.ext.MessageHandler should be initialized with an instance of a class that subclasses telegram.ext.BaseFilter and a callback function.
telegram.ext.filters.Text is such class and can be used to instantiate the MessageHandler either as:
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Text(), handel_message))

or using the instance provided in the module.
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, handel_message))

The error "...missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'"
is from calling the filters.Text.check_update method with only the update argument.
When an instance of filters.Text is passed, filters.Text.check_update instance method is called with the bound instance aka self and update.

I m just following a video tutorial. lot of thing have been updated. thanks for help
